# Swift: SWReavealController Can't Swipe to close menu "only open with swipe"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

This is Slideout menu using SWRevealController Which run perfectly but can swipe to open but doesn't swipe to close the menu

After adding the library I did few changes but I did know where is the issue.

This is the code in the main viewcontroller

```
  @IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.revealViewController().delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    }


    self.revealViewController().delegate = self
    var swl = self.revealViewController()


    if swl != nil
    {
        swl.panGestureRecognizer()
        swl.tapGestureRecognizer()
    }



}



@IBAction func but_back(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.delegate = self
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.target=self.revealViewController()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action=Selector("revealToggle:")
    self.revealViewController().revealToggle(sender)

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}


func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition)
{
    if position == FrontViewPosition.Left     // if it not statisfy try this --> if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left
    {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        revealController.panGestureRecognizer().enabled=true
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
        revealController.panGestureRecognizer().enabled=false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are disabling the pan gesture recognizer, along with disabling user interaction on your view, when the the reveal view controller front position is not at the left position in your delegate method implementation for `revealController:willMoveToPosition:` from `SWRevealViewControllerDelegate`. Therefore, the reveal view controller can only move to a single position. You can change that code to allow the additional positions that you require.

For example, if you comment out this code

```
func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition)
{
    if position == FrontViewPosition.Left     // if it not statisfy try this --> if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left
    {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        revealController.panGestureRecognizer().enabled=true
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
        revealController.panGestureRecognizer().enabled=false
    }
}
```

that should prevent the disabling of the pan gesture unnecessarily.

If you need to disable the reveal view controller pan gesture, I'd suggest using the delegate method `revealControllerPanGestureShouldBegin:` from `SWRevealViewControllerDelegate`.

Comment: It appears you are disabling the pan gesture recognizer unnecessarily. If you stop doing that by removing that code or commenting it out, does it fix your problem? I've added the code that I'm referring to in my answer.

Comment: wow it works well ,I wasted hours trying to fix it thank you very much

Comment: Fantastic. I'm glad I could help. I want to point out also you may be adding additional pan gesture recognizers unnecessarily in your `but_back( )` function. Adding it once in `viewDidLoad:` should be sufficient.

Comment: yes I did comment that and it still functional thank you bro