# Disable front view interaction SWRevealController

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller, user-interaction

I have set up an [SWRevealController menu](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) that slides out from the right side of my app. I have a button on the right hand side of my navigation bars that reveals the menu. I am trying to disable user interaction on the front view when the menu is open. I have tried following [this](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/92) but i am struggling. The class name that controls the menu is `menuTableViewController.swift`. Can someone explain how i do this in swift?

Comment: what the problem u faced...

Comment: Under the 'Swiftified' comment, i dont know what `self.revealViewController().delegate = self` is

Comment: `self.revealViewController()` -- > if you use some delegate methoos , you need to implement

Comment: see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025802/swift-swreavealcontroller-cant-swipe-to-close-menu-only-open-with-swipe/33026934